# jQuery: get actual height of element (or its children) when css min-height is set?

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I have `div.box`es with multiple elements in it, an image, two textboxes and a link. The elements in the `div.box` are filled dynamically so it could be multiple lines of text or a bigger or smaller image. Anyway, I'm applying a `min-height:210px;` to this `div.box`es.

210px is the maximum height those elements inside it can have in height. My page layout is actually depending on this value of 210px so it can't be higher.

However it can be smaller then this 210px so I want to use jQuery to retrieve the actual height of the element (if there wouldn't be set a min-height)?

Is that possible? So right now, if I'm trying to do `$("div.box").height()` it will always return 210px because that is the height of the element. How can I get the height if this min-height css value wouldn't be set? Do I have to get the height of each child and then add them together?

Thank you in advance…

edit: That's a bit complicated. I'm using min-height because I have a grid layout where 4 of those div.boxes are side by side. There are multiple rows. If I don't use min-height value and one of the boxes is less than the other boxes, the next row of the boxes will jump out of the grid and align to the hightest div box the row above (the div boxes are floated)

The reason why I'm trying to fix this with jQuery is, that I want set always one row's div-box height to the hightest box in this row. Is that somehow understandable?

So right now all div-boxes are min-height:210px which means all boxes have the same height. As I said it's a grid of boxes, e.g. 4x4 or so. Now the grid is totally perfect because all boxes have the same height. However imagine the all boxes in the first row have a small image, a one-line text don't fill the 210px of the div-box height. So the gap between the first row of boxes to the second row of boxes doesn't optically look good - there is too much spacing.

That's the reason why I want to find out the actual height of one div.box so I can apply the largest value always to a set of four boxes. So all rows would have individual heights …

Guess nobody could ever understand that without a sample :)

edit edit:
or is it actually possible to apply a clear or so to every 4th element of the boxes via css? that would be the solution though

Comment: If the `div.box` height cannot be more than `210px`, why are you using `min-height` instead of `max-height`. Or am i missing something!?

Comment: I get it man. Check my update.

Comment: Have a look at me Edited answer. Solution via CSS. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `-min-height` of 210, `.height()` will always return 210px, unless the elements inside expands `div.box` to a bigger height.

What you could do is remove the `min-height` completely and rely solely on `.height()`.

I also think you got a bit confused when writing your question, because you mention `min-height:210` and then you say *210px is the maximum height those elements inside*...

Anyway, I have created a simple jsFiddle to demonstrate what I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/HpZX9/

****EDIT**

If you want to use CSS to clear every 4th `div.box` use the following code:

```
.box:nth-child(4n) {
    clear: both; /* left, both, right, none */
}
```

****EDIT EDIT**
Here's a solution with jQuery. Find the highest div http://jsfiddle.net/J4EpN/

Answer (score 1):

<s>Like i said in my comment,</s>

If you change the `min-height` to `max-height`, and then if you do `.height()` you will get what you want.

How about getting the `top` value of the `last child` in the `div.box` relative to the `div.box` and adding it with `last child's` height.

Some thing like this,

```
var $box = $('.box');

var lastChildPos = $(':last-child', $box).position();
var lastChildHeight = $(':last-child', $box).height();

alert(lastChildPos .top + lastChildHeight);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/5gr7Y/2/)(Updated).

Comment: Thank you, but read my edit in my question. The problem is I can not use `max-height` because my floated boxes would jump out of the grid. I have always four boxes in a row. If this boxes have individual heights the floating wouldn't work. The next rows elements would not start at the first grid position but would float to the highest box in the first row …

Answer (score 0):

it's solution:

[min-height refrence](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) said the default value of it is `0`,so,to reset min-height to the default value can get the absolute height of the box.

js:

```
(function() {
  var abusolute_height, box, _min_height;
  box = $(".box");
  /*
  get _min_height
  _min_height maybe the min-height
  */
  _min_height = box.height();
  /*
  get absulute height
  */
  box.css({
    "min-height": 0
  });
  abusolute_height = box.height();
  if (_min_height > abusolute_height) {
    /*
        if the height of box is the min-height
        reset it
        */
    box.css({
      "min-height": _min_height
    });
  }
  alert("min height:" + _min_height);
  alert("abusolute height:" + abusolute_height);
}).call(this);
```

but at last the `absulote height` to display is `_min_height`.

check here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/island205/egRHQ/1/)